# Woocommerce Payment System

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Salutations!

I want to crate a payment system on Woocommerce. That accept code payment(like how you recharge your phone), My website will only have items with one price so it will be easy.

So the problem is that I want my plugin/system to generate by its on codes(like 100 unique codes)...in which the person can buy items with the codes, not a discount like coupons.

I do not know hoe to start, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you wish to provide a payment method that requires the buyer to provide some random card number which your plugin must generate and store in a table.

Since you don't wish to use a voucher for this purpose I suggest you develop a payment extension to handle the process, however ensure you do series of tests before you go live.

Here is a tutorial that will get you started on woo commerce payment extension plugin. You can also see woo commerce documentation

http://www.sitepoint.com/ http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-woocommerce-payment-extension/